# Remove double quotes from query codeigniter 3

Tags: sql, oracle11g, codeigniter-3

When I use the `get()` method in codeigniter I get following query as result:

```
SELECT * FROM "table_users" WHERE "mail" = 'test@test.com'
```

instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE mail = 'test@test.com'
```

This causes it to not work correctly with Oracle 11g as the double quotes should not go with the table name.

I got the following error:

```
Error Number: 942

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

SELECT * FROM "table_usuarios" WHERE "correo" = 'test@test.com'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/Tecnologico/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, at least temporarily.

Editing the file system/database/DB_driver.php

into the query() function we add the following line:

```
    $sql = str_replace('"',"",$sql);
```

Just before the comment:

```
    // Run the Query
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).